# Find the convergence/divergence of a recursive formula that involves a summation of all previous terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I was wondering if the following infinite sequence converges or diverges:

First in words:
The next term equals the previous term plus one divided by the sum of all previous terms. The first term is equal to one.

Second as equation:
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{\sum_{x=0}^{n-1}a_x}$$ where $$a_0=1$$

Third as code:

$a_n=1$

$sum=1$

For i=1 to $\infty$

$a_n=a_n+1/sum$

$sum=sum+a_n$

Next i

If I expressed that correctly, the first 3 terms (starting with $a_0$) you get should be 1, 2, 2.33333

This is my first post on stack exchange; sorry if I don't have the right notation.

Answer (score 1):

It diverges.

From the recursion, we can see that $a_n>a_{n-1}$, and so this is a monotonically increasing sequence and will converge if and only if it is bounded above. Suppose $M>a_n$ for all $n$. Then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k < Mn$$ and so $$ a_n > a_{n-1} + \frac{1}{Mn}$$
Iterating this estimate, we get that 
$$a_n>\frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}$$

The right hand side is a partial sum of the harmonic series (times a constant) which is known to tend to $\infty$. Thus $a_n$ cannot be bounded above and must diverge